# How to limit clicks on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, flip

My idea is to create flipping card game. When user flip the card he receives the points, which are randomly generated. Okay, now the user can flip the card and check how much points he will receive, but I want to limit how many cards he can flip. For example, there are 4 cards now. Only 2 of them should be able to open. I'll be thankful for every advice.

```js
$('.front').html('dd');

$('.card').each(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("flipped");
  });
});

function getNumber() {
  $('.card .back').each(function() {
    var minNumber = 0;
    var maxNumber = 2;
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
    $(this).html(randomnumber);
  });
}

getNumber();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of cards which can be flipped, add a condition to the `click` handler which checks how many cards there are with the class `flipped`. If two already exist then you can disallow any further clicks from having an effect.

Also note that you don't need the `each()` loop to add a `click()` handler to multiple elements. Similarly you don't need a loop to set the `html()`, just provide a function which returns the value to set. Try this:

```js
$('.front').html('dd');

$('.card').on("click", function() {
  if ($('.flipped').length < 2) {
    $(this).addClass("flipped");
  } else {
    console.log('You already flipped two cards!');
  }
});

function getNumber() {
  var minNumber = 0;
  var maxNumber = 2;

  $('.card .back').html(function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
  });
}

getNumber();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Working great! Thank you!